# my android app working on pc but not work in .apk file(it could not open)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

iam try to generate qrcode and stores it in device but it does not working in android device but it works in pc

here i attached my full code

main.py

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager

import qrcode

from kivy.utils import platform
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
#from kivymd.uix.list import MDListItem, MDListItemHeadlineText
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.toast import toast


class Function(ScreenManager):
    global contacts
    contacts=[]
    
    
    def generate(self,root):
        
        if self.ids.item.text=="" and self.ids.box.text=="":
            toast("Please Enter The No Items And Box")
        elif self.ids.item.text=="":
            toast("Please Enter The No Items")
        elif self.ids.box.text=="":
            toast("Please Enter The No Box")
            
        elif self.ids.text.text!="":
            code= qrcode.QRCode(version=1.0,box_size=15,border=4)
            print(self.listToStr)
            if self.listToStr.strip()!=self.ids.text.text:
                print("value not same")
                toast("Value Not Same!")
            
            else:
                
                code.add_data("Plenum Info Sys-Cbe /n")
                code.add_data(self.ids.text.text)
                code.add_data(self.ids.item.text)
                code.add_data(self.ids.box.text)
                img=code.make_image(fill='Black',back_color='White')
        
                code.make(fit=True)
                if platform=="android":
                    from jnius import autoclass
                    env=autoclass("android.os.Environment")
                    path=env.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

                    img.save(f'{path}/{self.ids.text.text}.png')
                    self.ids.img.source=f"{path}/{self.ids.text.text}.png"
                else:
                
                    img.save(f'{self.ids.text.text}.png')
                    self.ids.img.source=f"{self.ids.text.text}.png"

                
                
                #img.save(f'{self.ids.text.text}.png')
                self.ids.item1.text=self.ids.item.text
                self.ids.box1.text=self.ids.box.text
                
                self.all_reset()
                root.current="second"
                
        else:
            toast("Please Scan or Enter The Data Value")
            print("invalid")
        self.all_reset()
    def viewimg(self,root):
        #root.stop()
        Window.close()
          
    
     
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        #self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.data_tables1 = MDDataTable(
            # MDDataTable allows the use of size_hint
            size_hint=(0.8, 0.85),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Data", dp(30))
                
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1","61"),
                ("2","62"),
                ("3","63"),
                ("4","64"),
                ("5","65"),
                ("6","66"),
                ("7","67"),
                ("8","68"),
                ("9","69"),
                ("10","70")

            ]
            
        )
        self.data_tables2 = MDDataTable(
            # MDDataTable allows the use of size_hint
            size_hint=(0.8, 0.85),
            use_pagination=True,
            check=True,
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("Data", dp(30))
                
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("1","51"),
                ("2","52"),
                ("3","53"),
                ("4","54"),
                ("5","55"),
                ("6","56"),
                ("7","57"),
                ("8","58"),
                ("9","59"),
                ("10","60")

            ]
            
        )
        #self.data_tables.bind(on_row_press=self.on_row_press)
        #self.ids.body.add_widget(self.data_tables)

        value=["1001","1002","1003"]
        menu_items = [
            {
                "text": f"Item {i}",
                "viewclass": "OneLineListItem",
                "on_release": lambda x=f"{i}": self.menu_callback(x),
            } for i in value
        ]
        self.menu = MDDropdownMenu(
            caller=self.ids.button,
            items=menu_items,
            width_mult=4,
        )
    def checked(self, instance_table, current_row):
        
        if current_row[1] not in contacts:
            contacts.append(current_row[1])
        else:
            contacts.remove(current_row[1])
        self.listToStr = ''.join(contacts)
        """for self.contact in self.contacts:
            self.contact=str(self.contact)
            self.contact+"""
        print(self.listToStr.strip())
    """def on_row_press(self, instance_table, instance_row):
        pass
        
        '''Called when a table row is clicked.'''
        print(instance_table, instance_row)
        index = instance_row.index
        cols_num = len(instance_table. column_data)
        row_num = int(index/cols_num)
        col_num = index%cols_num
        cell_row =instance_table.table_data.view_adapter.get_visible_view(row_num*cols_num)
        if cell_row.ids.check.state == 'normal':
            instance_table.table_data.select_all('normal')
            cell_row.ids.check.state = 'down'
        else:
            cell_row.ids.check.state = 'normal'
        instance_table.table_data.on_mouse_select(instance_row)"""

    def menu_callback(self, text_item):
        
        print(text_item)
        if text_item=="1001":
            self.table_clear()
            self.data_tables1.bind(on_check_press=self.checked)
            self.ids.body.add_widget(self.data_tables1)
        elif text_item=="1002":
            self.table_clear()
            self.data_tables2.bind(on_check_press=self.checked)
            self.ids.body.add_widget(self.data_tables2)
            
        
            pass
    def all_reset(self):
        self.ids.text.text=""
        self.ids.item.text=""
        self.ids.box.text=""
        self.ids.body.clear_widgets()
    def table_clear(self):
        self.ids.body.clear_widgets()
        
            
            
            
    

    

class MyApp(MDApp):
    
   

    
    
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_file("design.kv")
        if platform=="android":
            from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
            request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                             Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
            window.maximize()
        else:
            Window.size=(360,640)
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette="DeepOrange"
        
        
        return Function()
if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

design.kv file

:
Screen:
name:'first'

```
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        padding: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.55,"center_y":.9}
        MDLabel:
            text:"Packing No:"

    MDRaisedButton:
        id: button
        text: "Select No"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .65, "center_y": .9}
        on_release: root.menu.open()
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        id:button_tab
        size_hint_y:None
        height: dp(48)

    

    BoxLayout:
        id:body  


    

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        padding: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.55,"center_y":.2}
        MDTextField:
            id:text
            hint_text:"Enter Data"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.3,.1)
        padding: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.2,"center_y":.3}
        MDTextField:
            id:item
            hint_text:"No Of Items"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: (.3,.1)
        padding: "10dp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x":.70,"center_y":.3}
        MDTextField:
            id:box
            hint_text:"No Of Box"
    
    
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Generate"
        on_release: root.generate(root)
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.3,'center_y':.1}
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "Exit"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.7,'center_y':.1}
        on_release: root.viewimg(root)
Screen:
    name:'second'
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .6
        pos_hint: {'center_y':.5}
        padding: 10
        Image:
            id: img
    MDLabel:
        text:"Generated QR Code"
        font_style: 'H4'
        pos_hint: {'center_y':.9}
        halign:'center'
    MDLabel:
        text:"No Of Items:"
        font_style: 'H4'
        font_size:"15px"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.6,"center_y":.8}
    MDLabel:
        id: item1
        text:"Items"
        font_style: 'H4'
        font_size:"20px"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.85,"center_y":.8}
    MDLabel:
        text:"No Of Box:"
        font_style: 'H4'
        font_size:'15px'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':1.1,'center_y':.8}
    MDLabel:
        id: box1
        text:"Box"
        font_style: 'H4'
        font_size:'20px'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':1.3,'center_y':.8}


    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: "OK"
        pos_hint: {'center_x':.7,'center_y':.1}
        on_release: root.current="first"
```

I try to run apk file when click butto and show qrcode

but it does not work on .apk file but works on pc

i create barcode generator app using qrcode,